# NullPointerException in Android App

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, arrays, wav

I'm trying to create an app that will draw with the AndroidPlot library the waveform of a WAV file stored in raw.
Then, first of all what I do is to get the byte array of the waveform.
As I guess it is stored in pairs of 2 bytes, I try to get the amplitude of each of them and I store it in an int array which will be later converted into a Number array. I jut want to try the first 100 samples of the byte array for the moment.
This is the code that I have so far:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Number[] n = new Number[51];
    int[] array = new int[51];

    try {
        byte [] payload = IOUtils.toByteArray(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.radio));
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i+=2) {
            // convert byte pair to int
           int j=i/2; 
           int audioSample = (int) ((payload[i+1] & 0xff) << 8) | (payload[i] & 0xff)/ 32767;
            array[j]=audioSample;
            n[j] = (Number)array[j];
            j++;
        }
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     XYSeries series1 = new SimpleXYSeries(
                Arrays.asList(n),          // SimpleXYSeries takes a List so turn our array into a List
                SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, // Y_VALS_ONLY means use the element index as the x value
                "Series1");

    LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, null);


    // add a new series' to the xyplot:
    plot.addSeries(series1, series1Format);

    // reduce the number of range labels
    plot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(3);
    plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainLabelOrientation(-45);


}
```

When I try to compile the code I have a NullPointerException error.
I guess is something wrong with tha arrays.
Could you please help me? I am quite new on Java

```
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.representaaudio/com.example.representaaudio.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at android.util.TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.java:327)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at com.androidplot.util.PixelUtils.dpToPix(PixelUtils.java:103)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter.a(LineAndPointFormatter.java:101)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter.<init>(LineAndPointFormatter.java:63)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter.<init>(LineAndPointFormatter.java:74)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at com.example.representaaudio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:76)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Can we see all of the error message?

Comment: Please provide stacktrace.

Comment: You should clarify the line that throws the exception. For instance, is it the one where you declare the payload array?

Comment: It should be the byte [] payload.. but probably I am not doing it right, I am just quite new programming

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Plotstuff pixelUtils, you should call **init** method first

```
 /**
 * Recalculates scale value etc.  Should be called when an application starts or
 * whenever the screen is rotated.
 */
public static void init(Context ctx) {
    //DisplayMetrics dm = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    //SCALE = dm.density;
    //X_PIX = dm.widthPixels;
    //Y_PIX = dm.heightPixels;
    metrics = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `null` to the constructor for `LineAndPointFormatter`, instead of an instance of `PointLabelFormatter`

```
LineAndPointFormatter series1Format = new LineAndPointFormatter(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, null);
```

Create a PointLabelFormatter and pass it in to resolve this error.

Comment: @paviflo - are you getting the *same* error, or are you just getting a different null pointer exception?  Check your error message and make sure the line numbers are referring to the same code.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have your answer with the stacktrace, check your `PixelUtils` class or the `LineAndPointFormatter`, maybe you need to pass something instead of `null` in the constructor.

```
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at android.util.TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.java:327)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at com.androidplot.util.PixelUtils.dpToPix(PixelUtils.java:103)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter.a(LineAndPointFormatter.java:101)
02-06 18:45:30.946: E/AndroidRuntime(2642):     at com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter.<init>(LineAndPointFormatter.java:63)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code, one can only guess, but a possible cause seems to be the `payload` variable declaration

A simple approach to debug that part of the code would be to declare different variables for the output of `getResources()` and of `openRawResource()`. If any of these methods returns `null`, or if the value of the `R.raw.radio` parameter is `null`, then a `NullPointerException` will be thrown.